# How to segment by specific event Action Label in Google Analytics Reporting API

Tags: python, google-analytics

I am working in python but believe this affects all languages.

I am recording events with numerical values:

```
Action , Label , Value
Nights , 3 , 3
Days , 5 , 5
```

So two different Event Actions have Labels that are Values.

I would like to filter in the GA Reporting API for people who's 'Nights' action = '3' - regardless of the Days label, an see the goal conversion for that specific segment.

I don't see a way of doing this?

I tried using a filter 'ga:eventAction==Nights' and dynamic segment 'ga:eventLabel==3', but when I do this, GA reporting stops report goal conversions (everything is zero)

Answer (score 2):

if anybody finds this, I've resolved this by making sure my labels contain a unique identifier so I know what action they are. I also don't get goal conversions but just number of goals. I do this in Python! Shout if you want code or a demo!

Comment: I think I'm reaching the same conclusion. For segmenting purposes, labels need to be unique as well, because there seems to be no way of segmenting based on a "action, label" pair.